# How should I structure the data layer of a node.js server using node-postgres client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, architecture, node-postgres

I am working on a server in Node.js that uses node-postgres database client. I am trying to follow the 3 layer architecture (*controllers*, *services*, *models*). So far I have been using a *Pool* for all queries. However, now I need to perform transactions and that requires a single client throughout the whole transaction. I came up with a solution to pass an optional *client* parameter into the query function (without supplying the *client*, the query will be performed on the default *pool*). This way, the service layer can create a *client* and call other *services* that perform database operations with the created *client* in order to perform a transaction. However this means I will also have to add the optional *client* parameter into every *service* that is responsible for retrieving the data. Is the solution I came up with a good approach or are there any better solutions? Iam also unsure how should the *model layer* look like without using an ORM and wasn't able to find any examples. Would you say I should use an ORM like *sequalize*? I will appreciate any advice, so feel free to point out anything.

#### Code example:

**./db/index.js**

```js
const { Pool, Client } = require("pg");
const config = require("../config");

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: config.databaseURL,
  max: 20,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

/**
 * @param {object} obj
 * @param {string} obj.query
 * @param {any[]} [obj.values]
 * @param {Client} [obj.client]
 */
exports.query = ({ query, values, client }) => {
  return client === undefined
    ? pool.query(query, values)
    : client.query(query, values);
};

// returns the client
exports.connect = () => {
  return pool.connect();
};
```

**./models/pipe.model.js**

```js
const db = require("../db");

/**
 * @param {number | string} id ID of the pipe
 * @param {import("pg").Client} [client]
 */
exports.getById = (id, client) => {
  const query = `SELECT id, price, state, tone_id, rank_id FROM pipe
    WHERE id = $1`;
  return db.query({ query, values: [id], client });
};
```

**./services/pipe.service.js**

```js
const pipeModel = require("../models/pipe.model");
const StatusError = require("../helpers/error");

/**
 * @param {number | string} id
 * @param {import("pg").Client} [client]
 */
exports.getById = async (id, client) => {
  let rows, rowCount;
  try {
    ({ rows, rowCount } = await pipeModel.getById(id, client));
  } catch (err) {
    throw new StatusError(500, "Error retrieving data");
  }
  if (rowCount !== 1) {
    throw new StatusError(404, "Pipe with gived ID not found");
  }
  return rows[0];
};
```

Comment: Using Sequelize would help you a lot not to write many plain SQL CRUD queries and so on.